# Get Total Count of Unique Items of Generic List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I've been racking by brain all night (again) looking to get the total count of each set of unique items in a list. I was able to get the unique list items. But I can't seem to figure out how to get the count of each group of unique items. Please tell me if this makes sense. Below's my code:

```
    List<string> categories = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        categories.Add(item.Category);
    }
    IEnumerable<string> distinctCategories = categories.Distinct();                                                                      

        foreach (string category in distinctCategories)
        {
        <a href="http://localhost:62087/Items/SearchIndex?itemCategory=@category">@category @category.Count()</a>
        }
```

As you can see, I have a link displayed for each unique item in my Model's "Category" property (Item.Category). Where you see the category count at the end of the link it actually displays the number of characters in the category (such as the number 5 for the category "Rings"). But I really want the number to represent the number of times the category "Rings", for example, is found in the Model's Categories property.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the count, you need to use a `GroupBy` instead of `Distinct`:

```
var distinctCategories =
    categories.GroupBy(x => x)
              .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, ItemsCount = g.Count() });
foreach (var category in distinctCategories)
{
    <a href="http://localhost:62087/Items/SearchIndex?itemCategory=@category.Name">@category.Name @category.ItemsCount</a>
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote is giving me an error: cannot convert method group to non-delegate type object. Any thoughts?

Comment: @iDevJunkie: Please make sure you have the code exactly as I do. Especially, don't miss the parentheses on `g.Count()`.

Comment: Hmm, I copied and pasted. Just did it again and it works perfectly. Man, beautiful work! Thank you soooooo much!